# How can I show audio level for a video being played back?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation

I'm using `AVPlayer` to play a video file in my app, and I'd like to have a slider-function to control the volume, AND show the current power/level(metering), which looks like this ([LARSBar](https://github.com/larsacus/LARSBar)):

[image: LARSBar]

This element is intended for recording, but I am trying to make it work for playback of video. Is it any way to 'listen'/register for the output volume of an AVPlayer? I can't find anything on the matter. I have realized it might not be possible, but I was hoping I at least could 'listen' for the entire output-connection for the phone itself, even though that would mean it would pick up sounds like incoming SMS-alerts etc. I do, however, not know where to look or what to search for.

Comment: Look at Apple's MTAudioProcessingTap example. It shows how to instal an MTAudioProcessingTap and meter the volume of playback.